How can I make this equation look better?
The equation is
\[
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\rmd}{\dx} \begin{vmatrix}
    f_{11}(x) & f_{12}(x) & \cdots & f_{1n}(x) \\
    f_{21}(x) & f_{22}(x) & \cdots & f_{2n}(x) \\
    \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
    f_{n1}(x) & f_{n2}(x) & \cdots & f_{nn}(x) \\
\end{vmatrix} \\ = 
\sum_{k=1}^n \begin{vmatrix}
    f_{11}(x) & f_{12}(x) & \cdots & f_{1n}(x) \\
    f_{21}(x) & f_{22}(x) & \cdots & f_{2n}(x) \\
    \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
    f_{k1}'(x) & f_{k2}'(x) & \cdots & f_{kn}'(x) \\
    \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots
    f_{n1}(x) & f_{n2}(x) & \cdots & f_{nn}(x) \\
\end{vmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\]

And I got this:

I also tried to ask ChatGPT, it suggested me to use align environment. I have no idea how to fix it. By the way, the document class is IEEEtran. Does it matter? I don't want to change documentclass.

How or where are \rmd and \dx defined?

Off-topic: Your code is missing a double-backslash directive at the end of second-to-last row of the second vmatrix environment.

\rmd and \dx are defined as:
\newcommand{\rmd}{\mathrm{d}}  \newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm{dx}}

I don't think that \newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm{dx}} is quite right: Only the letter "d" (the "differential operator"), but not the letter for the variable "x", should be rendered with an upright glyph. Put differently, give \newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm{d}x} a try.

you should always post a documement that people can use to see the problem and test answers, do not just post a fragment using undefined commands.

@Mico OK. Thanks for your advices.

@DavidCarlisle Alright, that's my fault lol.

The align(ed) environment aligns on the & (that aren't hiding in vmatrix).  Since you don't have any, LaTeX pretends there are some at the ends of your lines, and everything is right aligned.

In addition to providing a \\ (line break) directive in the second-to-last row of the second vmatrix environment, I suggest you (a) change from an aligned to a multlined environment and (b) increase the vertical separation between the two rows of display-math material slightly, by changing \\ to \\[\jot]. \jot is a length parameter whose default value is 3pt; if \\[\jot] doesn't add enough vertical separation for your taste, I suggest you try \\[5pt] or so. In other words, don't overdo this adjustment.

\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'multlined' environment
\usepackage{newtx} % for Times Roman text and math fonts (optional)

\providecommand\rmd{\mathrm{d}}  % ?
\providecommand\dx{\mathrm{d}x}  % ?

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{multlined}
\frac{\rmd}{\dx} 
\begin{vmatrix}
    f_{11}(x) & f_{12}(x) & \cdots & f_{1n}(x) \\
    f_{21}(x) & f_{22}(x) & \cdots & f_{2n}(x) \\
    \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
    f_{n1}(x) & f_{n2}(x) & \cdots & f_{nn}(x) \\
\end{vmatrix} \\[\jot] % default value of \jot: 3pt
= \sum_{k=1}^n 
\begin{vmatrix}
    f_{11}(x) & f_{12}(x) & \cdots & f_{1n}(x) \\
    f_{21}(x) & f_{22}(x) & \cdots & f_{2n}(x) \\
    \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
    f_{k1}'(x) & f_{k2}'(x) & \cdots & f_{kn}'(x) \\
    \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
    f_{n1}(x) & f_{n2}(x) & \cdots & f_{nn}(x) \\
\end{vmatrix}
\end{multlined}
\]

\end{document}


Does this looks better?

\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{\rm d}{dx} \begin{vmatrix}
    f_{11}(x) & f_{12}(x) & \cdots & f_{1n}(x) \\
    f_{21}(x) & f_{22}(x) & \cdots & f_{2n}(x) \\
    \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
    f_{n1}(x) & f_{n2}(x) & \cdots & f_{nn}(x) \\
\end{vmatrix} \\[9pt]
&\quad= 
\sum_{k=1}^n \begin{vmatrix}
    f_{11}(x) & f_{12}(x) & \cdots & f_{1n}(x) \\
    f_{21}(x) & f_{22}(x) & \cdots & f_{2n}(x) \\
    \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
    f_{k1}'(x) & f_{k2}'(x) & \cdots & f_{kn}'(x) \\
    \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\ % <-- added "\\"
    f_{n1}(x) & f_{n2}(x) & \cdots & f_{nn}(x) \\
\end{vmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}


I think you should add a line break instruction at the end of the second-to-last line in the second vmatrix.

@Mico Agreed with you, also I requested you to make the necessary changes in my post, please

I've updated your code and the screenshot. Incidentally, I think that \\[9pt] -- which could also be written as \\[3\jot] -- is too much of a good thing. Do consider using \\[2\jot], or even less, of a vertical spacing adjustment.

Yes, it works. Thanks.

@Mico Thanks a lot
